# Why doesn't Python's `except` use `isinstance`?

Tags: python, exception, types, isinstance

The [Python documentation](http://docs.python.org/reference/compound_stmts.html#the-try-statement) for `except` says:

> For an except clause with an
>   expression, that expression is
>   evaluated, and the clause matches the
>   exception if the resulting object is
>   “compatible” with the exception. An
>   object is compatible with an exception
>   if **it is the class or a base class of the exception object**, [...]

Why doesn't `except` use `isinstance` instead of comparing base classes? This is preventing the use of `__instancecheck__` to override the instance check.

**EDIT:**

I can understand that one of the reasons this doesn't exist is that no one considered it. But are there any reasons why this should not be implemented?

**EDIT:**

Shell session from Python 3.2a showing that trying to use `__subclasscheck__` for this doesn't work:

```
>>> class MyType(type): __subclasscheck__ = lambda cls, other_cls: True
>>> class O(Exception, metaclass=MyType): pass
>>> issubclass(3, O)
0: True
>>> issubclass(int, O)
1: True
>>> try:
...     1/0
... except O:
...     print('Success')
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<pyshell#4>", line 2, in <module>
    1/0
ZeroDivisionError: division by zero
>>>
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The simple answer is probably that nobody considered it. A more complex answer would be that nobody considered it because it's hard to get this right, because it would mean executing potentially arbitrary Python code *while handling an exception*, and that it is of dubious value. Exception classes in Python are typically very simple classes, and overloading them with functionality is often a mistake. It's hard to imagine a case for having it consult `__instancecheck__`. If you have such a case (with or without a patch), file a bug and someone might pick it up.

Comment: I can relate with the fact that nobody considered it. I guess what I'm asking is if there are good reasons not to do it.   *"it would mean executing potentially arbitrary Python code while handling an exception"*. I think I can give the "consenting adults" answer to that-- If someone wants to have a custom instance check in his exception handling, why not let him?

Answer (score 2):

> But are there any reasons why this
>   should not be implemented?

Can you give an example where this would be useful?

When you do this:

```
class SomeMeta(type):
    def __subclasscheck__(cls, sub):
        print (cls, sub)
        return True

class Something(Exception):
    pass

class SomeType(Exception):
    __metaclass__ = SomeMeta

try:
    raise Something()
except SomeType, e:
    pass

# prints (<class '__main__.SomeType'>, <class '__main__.Something'>)
```

Python calls `__subclasscheck__` on `SomeType`'s metaclass to determine if `Something` a subclass of `SomeType`. The [Metaclass PEP](http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-3119/#overloading-isinstance-and-issubclass) talks about this in more detail.

Comment: I tried your `__subclasscheck__` suggestion now on both 2.6 and 3.2a, unfortunately it didn't work. About your question: What do you mean in "concrete"? An example for this being useful?

Comment: Okay, I see that both our samples do work in 2.6, but not in 3.1 or 3.2a.

Comment: About an example where this would be useful: I have an idea of making something like `abc` for exceptions, so you can register an exception instance to be also an instance of a different exception type. This could prevent annoying traceback-hiding when catching an exception only to raise another.